# Would switching all my mods from the Steam Workshop to Nexus affect my current saves?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods, steam-workshop

I currently use workshop for some mods but recently installed nexus. Both systems work fine side by side. However, I would like to switch to using nexus only. I'd prefer just using one modding app for simplicity sake. Can anyone tell me, if I unsubscribe from the workshop version and install the nexus version of a mod (particularly follower mods), will I lose things like my followers, the items they are carrying, etc?

Comment: You might want to look at Mod Organizer. It's not exactly the same as NMM, but you can download mods from Nexus and actually manage them. Plus, you have mod profiles (with per-profile saves!) so you can test them before putting them into the game.

Comment: While not a direct part of the question, Mod Organizer should be the defacto to go to at this point in time instead of NMM. Especially if you are comfortable enough to manage both Workshop and nexus mods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. It's just a different way of downloading the files.

You might have problems with different versions of mods, but those should usually be minor.

But as always: **Back up your saves**.